# python recursion help for modifying lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, recursion, element

I have this code that can replace an existing sub string of a string with another sub string. i would want to modify it so that it can work for a list but I don't know how to do it. in other words, i want to modify it so that it can replace an existing element of a list with a new elements.I want to do it recursively.

```
def rec_replace(string, a, b):
    if not string: #if the string is empty
        return ""
    elif string[:len(b)] == b: #if the string start with b, replace it with a
        return a + rec_replace(string[len(b):], a, b)
    else: #else, add this character and go to the next one
        return string[0] + rec_replace(string[1:], a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're messing around for nothing. Just use:

```
lst[lst.index(old_element)]=new_element
```

If you want  it to replace all occurrences of old_element do it with a loop:

```
while old_element in lst:
    lst[lst.index(old_element)]=new_element
```

And for string just use:

```
string.replace(old_element,new_element)
```